# SWFUpload using https does not work in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, https, swfupload

SWFUpload I am using [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org) to upload files to a database (Windows XP) over https. Everything works as expected in IE (7 and 8), but using my Firefox 3.3.15 it fails without error message. Using the upload mechanism using http works fine!

I found this [thread](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/347) using google. They describe that installing the CAs certificate as trusted issuer would help. Unfortunatly it did not (it was a certificate issued by a CaCert authority).

It works on the machine of my colleague who uses Firefox 3.3.15, but he cannot recall that he did anything special to make it work. I had a look at other machines using Firefox and none of them were able to upload a file to the database.

I red that SWFUpload uses flash and that flash might use other certificates than Firefox itself. Does anyone know anything about it?

EDIT: This is the javascript code for the object creation:

```
// Create the SWFUpload Object
var swfupload_object = new SWFUpload({
    upload_url: "[% cgi_path %]/mdb_bulk_import.pl",
    file_post_name: 'upload_file',
    post_params:
    {
        "sid": "[% sid %]",
        "rm": "import",
        "tree_id": "[% tree_id %]"
    },
    flash_url: "[% system_url %]/flash/swfupload-2.2.0b3.swf",
    file_size_limit: "1000 MB",

    debug: false,
    //debug_handler: console.log,

    button_placeholder_id : "select-button",
    button_image_url : '[% system_url %]/image/button-bulk-upload.png',
    button_width : 160,
    button_text_top_padding : 3,
    button_height : 25,
    button_text: '<span class="select-button">[% cat.Msg_ChooseFiles %]</span>',
    button_text_style: '.select-button { position: absolute; top: 10px; display: block; padding-top: 15px; text-align: center; font-size: 11px; line-height: 10px; color: #000000; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }',
    button_action : SWFUpload.BUTTON_ACTION.SELECT_FILES,
    button_disabled : false,
    button_cursor : SWFUpload.CURSOR.HAND,
    button_window_mode : SWFUpload.WINDOW_MODE.OPAQUE,

    file_queued_handler: cb_file_queued,
    upload_start_handler: cb_upload_start,
    upload_progress_handler: cb_upload_progress,
    upload_complete_handler: cb_upload_complete
});
```

**What can i do to make it work?
Any suggestions?**

Comment: can you share bugy portion of code.

Comment: i may, but the code is not buggy (it seems like this problem is related to a flash bug)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you have self-signed certificate. Please read [this article](http://www.swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/347)

Comment: and what happens if i add the cert of the signing CA to the trusted CAs in my browser?